# Returning a one-dimensional array from function, how?

Tags: java, arrays

- How can I get contents of a one dimensional array via a public function?

---

this is my public method

```
    public class try 
{
    private String sname;
    private int[][] score;
    private int grade;
    private double average;

    public void names(String[] stuname)
    {
        String[] sname = new String[3];
        sname[0] = "Blair";
        sname[1] = "Waldorf";
        sname[2] = "Chuck";

    }
}
```

then this is my main method in other class file.

```
public class MainTry
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try a1 = new try();
        System.out.println(a1.sname[3]);
    }
}
```

there is a big mistake. i cant get it. im using netbeans.

Comment: Post you have already tried. Or at least try to be more precise in your question. This kind of question is not simple to be answered and is not a good one for stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
 // declare a string array with initial size
String[] names = new String[4];

// remember that the array starts at 0 so an array with 4 elements goes up to index number 3.
// add elements to the array
names[0] = "Freddy";
names[1] = "Fish";
names[2] = "Henry";
names[3] = "Tom";
```

This is how you make a one dimensional array with names in it.

Comment: One name.... not n names. But is not clear if he likes an array of char of strings of dimension 1 or something different

Comment: i just needed a tab of names in programming. because i need to put grades in the side of the names which is two dimensional. thanks derk :)

Comment: Did you figure it out by yourself or are you still encountering the same problem ?